# MDI and WPF Ribbon

Tags: wpf, xaml, mdi, ribbon

i noticed that the WPF Ribbon is bound to a XAML Usercontrol or window.

Lets imagine i have a windws.xaml page with a WPF Ribbon at the top.

I want to create an instance such that once i click on one of the WPF Buttons, i am taken to a different XAML UserControl or "page". How do i do this?

Will this new page have the WPF Ribbon on the top?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a Frame in a Window that showing a page and Navigate this?

```
<Frame
    Source="Page1.xaml"
    Name="frame1"  
    NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
```

And then use

```
frame1.Navigate(new Uri("Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

to Navigate from the button? (or use a command)

Answer (score 0):

I describe how to do this in my blog using the mvvm pattern.

http://wegged.com/2010/08/23/use-the-new-wpf-ribbon-like-a-tab-control/

Comment: the domain you link to is now for sale.  Can you update the link?